# Change email address of user who signed it with Google

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When using Firebase Auth, should I allow users to change their email address if they originally authenticated with Google?

How would I then handle this, when the user will not have a password and will not be able to log in with this new email address but will have to use the Sign In With Google option and log in with their original google email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link multiple authentication providers to one account - see the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking).

This way, they can choose to sign in any of the linked providers on another device or on the original device (e.g. after they've deleted and re-installed the application).